# How can I execute an ANTLR parser action for each item in a rule that can match more than one item?

Tags: parsing, antlr, grammar

I am trying to write an ANTLR parser rule that matches a list of things, and I want to write a parser action that can deal with each item in the list independently.

Some example input for these rules is:

```
$(A1 A2 A3)
```

I'd like this to result in an evaluator that contains a list of three `MyIdentEvaluator` objects -- one for each of A1, A2, and A3.

Here's a snippet of my grammar:

```
my_list returns [IEvaluator e]
    : { $e = new MyListEvaluator(); }
      '$'
      LPAREN
      op=my_ident+ { 
                     /* want to do something here for each 'my_ident'. */ 
                     /* the following seems to see only the 'A3' my_ident */
                     $e.Add($op.e);
                   }
      RPAREN
    ;

my_ident returns [IEvaluator e]
    : IDENT { $e = new MyIdentEvaluator($IDENT.text); }
    ;
```

I think `my_ident` is defined correctly, because I can see the three `MyIdentEvaluators` getting created as expected for my input string, but only the last `my_ident` ever gets added to the list (A3 in my example input).

How can I best treat each of these elements independently, either through a grammar change or a parser action change?

It also occurred to me that my vocabulary for these concepts is not what it should be, so if it looks like I'm misusing a term, I probably am.

---

EDIT in response to Wayne's comment:

I tried to use `op+=my_ident+`.  In that case, the `$op` in my action becomes an `IList` (in C#) that contains `Antlr.Runtime.Tree.CommonTree` instances.  It does give me one entry per matched token in `$op`, so I see my three matches, but I don't have the `MyIdentEvaluator` instances that I really want.  I was hoping I could then find a rule attribute in the ANTLR docs that might help with this, but nothing seemed to help me get rid of this `IList`.

---

Result...

Based on chollida's answer, I ended up with this which works well:

```
my_list returns [IEvaluator e]
    : { $e = new MyListEvaluator(); }
      '$'
      LPAREN
      (op=my_ident    { $e.Add($op.e); } )+
      RPAREN
    ;
```

The `Add` method gets called for each match of my_ident.

Comment: Not enough for me to answer your question, is the problem that $op does not contain all three tokens?  Or something else, like you want to do something specific for each token?  To get all three tokens into $op I think you need to have op+=my_ident+ (another plus sign in front of the equal sign).  More information would be required for me to answer the other question.

Comment: My problem is that I don't really know what "$op" really is.  I am getting there, thanks in part to your help on this and my other questions! I have the Terence Parr book on order. :)  Yes, I just want to be able to do the same thing to each token -- in this case, add the token to a list.  I will edit my question to reflect the result of the "op+" suggestion you made.

Comment: Ok, so the my_ident and return value from that rule plus the $op are all working as expected (wanted at this time).  Now to get the $e in my_list to return the correct object.  Should it be returning just the list that is $op?  I think one you want to modify the my_list rule at the beginning to be-
  my_list returns [IEvaluator e]
     @init{ $e = new MyListEvaluator(); }
     : '$' ...
Also, you might want to change your return label/variable in either my_ident or my_list; both of them being e can be a little confusing.
Next is the MyListEvaluator vs MyIdentEvaluator (I don't know C#).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I was writing this I'd split out the individual matching into a list pattern:

```
my_list returns [IEvaluator e]
: { $e = new MyListEvaluator(); }
  '$'
  LPAREN
  op=my_ident { $e.Add($op.e); }
  (opNext=my_ident { $e.Add($opNext.e); })*
  RPAREN
;


my_ident returns [IEvaluator e]
: IDENT { $e = new MyIdentEvaluator($IDENT.text); }
;
```

Here instead of using Antlr's built in `+` we do the iteration ourselves.  We match the first item and add it to the list, then we match successive items and store them.

Answer (score 1):

```
my_list returns [IEvaluator e]
  : '$' LPAREN ops+=my_ident+ RPAREN { e = new MyListEvaluator(list_ops); }
  ;
```

I'm doing something similar in Java and had to inspect the generated code to find that ANTLR3 generates a variables called "list_NAME" (where NAME=ops in this case) which is a list of all the sub-token rule return values. I imagine it's the same in C#, though I could be wrong. You would expect the variable to be called just "ops" but that variable will only ever contain the last matched rule value (in Java, at least).